# ¿Cómo pasar un XML DataTable xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Data" a un DataTable en C#?

Tags: c#, xml, soap

Estoy haciendo un consumo de un servicio Web desde mi app en `c#` y este me retorna la siguiente estructura:

```xml
<DataTable xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Data">
    <xs:schema id="NewDataSet" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" xmlns:msprop="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msprop">
        <xs:element name="NewDataSet" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:MainDataTable="Table" msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true">
            <xs:complexType>
                <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                    <xs:element name="Table">
                        <xs:complexType>
                            <xs:sequence>
                                <xs:element name="FUENTE" msprop:OraDbType="126" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                                <xs:element name="TIPO_DOC" msprop:OraDbType="126" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                                <xs:element name="NUIP" msprop:OraDbType="126" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                                <xs:element name="NOM1" msprop:OraDbType="126" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                                <xs:element name="NOM2" msprop:OraDbType="126" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                                <xs:element name="APE1" msprop:OraDbType="126" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                                <xs:element name="APE2" msprop:OraDbType="126" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                                <xs:element name="DEPTO_EXP" msprop:OraDbType="126" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                                <xs:element name="MUN_EXP" msprop:OraDbType="126" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                                <xs:element name="F_EXP" msprop:OraDbType="106" type="xs:dateTime" minOccurs="0"/>
                                <xs:element name="ESTADO_CEDULA" msprop:OraDbType="126" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                                <xs:element name="NUM_RESOL" msprop:OraDbType="107" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="0"/>
                                <xs:element name="ANO_RESOL" msprop:OraDbType="107" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="0"/>
                                <xs:element name="DOCUMENTO_CANCELADO" msprop:OraDbType="107" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="0"/>
                                <xs:element name="OBSERVACION" msprop:OraDbType="126" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                                <xs:element name="GENERO" msprop:OraDbType="126" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                                <xs:element name="FECHANACIMIENTO" msprop:OraDbType="106" type="xs:dateTime" minOccurs="0"/>
                                <xs:element name="F_CONSULTA" msprop:OraDbType="106" type="xs:dateTime" minOccurs="0"/>
                            </xs:sequence>
                        </xs:complexType>
                    </xs:element>
                </xs:choice>
            </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
    </xs:schema>
    <diffgr:diffgram xmlns:diffgr="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata">
        <NewDataSet xmlns="">
            <Table diffgr:id="Table1" msdata:rowOrder="0">
                <FUENTE>RNEC</FUENTE>
                <TIPO_DOC>CC</TIPO_DOC>
                <NUIP>54778455</NUIP>
                <NOM1>ANGEL</NOM1>
                <NOM2>MIREIDA</NOM2>
                <APE1>RAMOS</APE1>
                <APE2>VALLEJOS</APE2>
                <DEPTO_EXP>PERU</DEPTO_EXP>
                <MUN_EXP>RICAURTE</MUN_EXP>
                <F_EXP>1998-07-22T00:00:00-05:00</F_EXP>
                <ESTADO_CEDULA>VIGENTE</ESTADO_CEDULA>
                <NUM_RESOL>0</NUM_RESOL>
                <ANO_RESOL>0</ANO_RESOL>
                <DOCUMENTO_CANCELADO>0</DOCUMENTO_CANCELADO>
                <GENERO>FEMENINO</GENERO>
                <FECHANACIMIENTO>1978-04-14T00:00:00-05:00</FECHANACIMIENTO>
                <F_CONSULTA>2019-08-29T11:21:03-05:00</F_CONSULTA>
            </Table>
        </NewDataSet>
    </diffgr:diffgram>
</DataTable>
```

Y necesito pasar esa respuesta a una `clase` o a un `DataTable` como tal en `C#`, ya desde que pueda tener los datos en variables podría trabajarlo, pero no sé cómo poder convertir ese `XML` a un tipo de dato válido en mi programa.

Tengo esta clase para poder ingresar los datos, si de algo ayuda:

```cs
 class DataResultClass
    {
        string FUENTE { get; set; }
        string TIPO_DOC { get; set; }
        string NUIP { get; set; }
        string NOM1 { get; set; }
        string NOM2 { get; set; }
        string APE1 { get; set; }
        string APE2 { get; set; }
        string DEPTO_EXP { get; set; }
        string MUN_EXP { get; set; }
        string F_EXP { get; set; }
        string ESTADO_CEDULA { get; set; }
        string NUM_RESOL { get; set; }
        string ANO_RESOL { get; set; }
        string DOCUMENTO_CANCELADO { get; set; }
        string GENERO { get; set; }
        string FECHANACIMIENTO { get; set; }
        string F_CONSULTA { get; set; }
    }
```

Para consumir el servicio uso lo siguiente:

```cs
HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("urlservice.svc") as HttpWebRequest;
request.Method = "GET";
HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
string resp = reader.ReadToEnd();
```

Comment: se trata de un servicio, no tendrias que convertir ningun xml, como estas consumiendo el servicio web? estas creando una web reference? es un .asmx o un .svc

Comment: es un svc, y lo consumo mediante `HttpWebRequest`

Comment: porque usas el HttpWebRequest ? eso es incorrecto, deberias crear un `Service Reference`

Comment: Lo que sucede es que el servicio no es solo el SVC, luego del .svc, debo agregar datos que son variables a cada consumo, por qué añadir una referencia de servicio no podría enviar los diferentes datos en cada solicitud

Comment: La url se compone de algo así `http://urlservice/service.svc/CONSULTA/PARAM1,PARAM2,PARAM3`

Comment: Y hay otra que es algo así: `http://urlservice/service.svc/CONSULTA/PARAM1/PARAM2/PARAM3,PARAM4,PARAM5`
Es por eso que lo hago mediante el `httpWebRequest`

Comment: No veo que tiene que ver un servicio con el agregado de parametros, si es un servicio WCF lo que explicas no aplica, accede al wsdl y crea el service reference

Comment: siempre podras indicar parametros en la url del service reference, ya que desde codigo se puede cambiar la url

Comment: Los dueños del servicio me dijeron que el servicio lo leyera con petición REST, que así se consume perfectamente. Dado que al intentar añadir la referencia web siempre me aparecian errores de la referencia, no la encontraba o cosas así

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Lo solucioné agregando

```cs
XmlTextReader xmlreader = new XmlTextReader(new System.IO.StringReader(resp));
DataContractSerializer ser = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(DataTable));
DataTable datos = (DataTable)ser.ReadObject(xmlreader);
```

para que al final, me quedará mi código así:

```cs
HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("urlservice.svc") as HttpWebRequest;
request.Method = "GET";
HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
string resp = reader.ReadToEnd();
XmlTextReader xmlreader = new XmlTextReader(new System.IO.StringReader(resp));
DataContractSerializer ser = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(DataTable));
DataTable datos = (DataTable)ser.ReadObject(xmlreader);
```

Comment: esa no es la solucion si el servicio es un svc

Comment: A mi se me solucionó, según como lo estoy manejando, por eso dejé mi código y las explicaciones del por qué lo hago así, así que para mi esta es la respuesta.

Comment: ok, me alegro que lo resolvieras, pero no es la solucion correcta, es solo un parche para resolver tu caso en concreto

Comment: Cómo lo resolverías tu?, ya tienes los ejemplos de mis URL a consumir

Comment: Si partimos que es un servicio de WCF, por eso el .svc y no es un servicio de algun otro tipo que uso esa extension, entonces el primer paso seria creando el service reference, asi tendras el proxy y ademas los datos se generaran como class, sin necesidad de parsear ningun xml. Si la url necesita parametros el proxy al instanciarse expone la propiedad donde indicar la url en caso de necesitar redefinirla con parametros. Aunque igual haber desarrollador el servicio de esa forma fue uan pesima idea, para eso se exponen los parametros que debe recibir el servicio por POST.

Comment: Lo que dices no me resuelve nada, como te dije, ya tienes como funcionan las URL, si puedes recrear un ejemplo y explicar como haces para consumirlo perfectamente como dices puedo tomarlo como una respuesta que puede considerarse valida.

Comment: pero sabes lo que es un service reference? lo usaste anteriormente? pudiste instanciar el proxy que se genera en base al wsdl (sin parametros en la url) y ver esa propiedad que menciona donde indicarias la url a la cual la asignarias los parametros. Ademas explicar algo cuando ya tienes tu respuesta y no estar abierto a probar alternativas, no tiene sentido